# How to make RowCreated event not to fire when it is not postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with dynamic controls in `RowCreated` event. In the `gridview` columns there are `server controls`.

For ex I have a `LinkButton` control, when I click the button it is again creating all the controls on the page in the `RowCreated` event. Which is eating out so much time.

How can I prevent from that event being called and have those `controls`

**My code :**

```
                        Button btn = new Button();
                        btn.ID = "button1";
                        btn.Text = "Submit";
                        btn.Click += btn_Click;
                        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>A simple way would be to add `if (!IsPostBack)...` to your RowCreated event.</s>

Unfortunately, dynamic controls must be recreated on postback. Retaining values can sometimes get tricky, but if you work with the [Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7.aspx) correctly, you should be OK.

There are other areas where you can look for optimizations, particularly [caching your datasource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227994(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: If I do that I'm loosing my already existing controls @Micheal

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik It's difficult to tell without more context. Is that code the complete contents of your `RowCreated` event method? Could we see the `btn_Click` code? One potential solution, depending on your needs, is show/hide an existing control, rather than creating it dynamically. Much easier to manage!

Comment: On Button Click just normal methods to retrieve data and show them on the page

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik I just realised that I might be misinterpreting your question -- is your code functioning correctly, but it's just taking too long to render... is that the case?

Comment: Yes, and I don't want to load for every `postback` and retain already binded controls and their values